# How to re-select something in a <select> element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, what is the most simple and elegant way to re-select an item in a `<select>` dropdown list when given chosen_value=111?

What if it is checkboxes instead of `<select>`, having `id[]=11&id[]=12`...  (the [] are actually in %5B%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dropdownlist, just set the value using the val() function.

```
$("#mySelect").val(chosen_value);
```

For the checkboxes, you can set all the values at once if you can get the array of checkbox names that should be checked.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").val(["checkbox1", "checkbox3", "checkbox4"]);
```